# MySQL security and symfony2

Tags: mysql, security, symfony, localhost

Working with Symfony2.3.4 and Xampp with PHP 5.6.3.

Basically my goal is to prevent anyone from tampering with the database tables directly via any manager(for example: phpmyadmin which comes with xampp via localhost/phpmyadmin/)

I'd like to find a way to set a password.

I looked for an option in phpmyadmin to set some type of security and found none.

I tried to set a password for the database via the config interface provided by the AcmeDemoBundle which i've always used to set the **parameters.yml**, all that did was to throw this at my face:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I need to know what I'm missing, is there a way to continue from here, or am I doing it wrong right from the beginning.

Remember: the goal is to let no one without authorization access the tables of the database in any way.

thank you

Comment: IMO, phpMyAdmin should never be on a production server.

Comment: I can't tell the network administrator what to or not to install in his server,
all I want is to prevent access to __my__ database, I guess I'll have to keep looking

Comment: The [MySQL Privilege System](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html) is a good place to start looking.  Just make sure no account except for the one you want to access your database has any privileges on it and no one will be able to access or modify it.

Comment: You have problem with MySQL.

Check users table:

`SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user;` and remove/add users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found what I needed [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22374/how-to-login-as-another-user-in-phpmyadmin), answered by Anagio,
in the end what I had to do was to change the **auth_type** from *config* to *http* and voilá, a prompt appears when I hit localhost/phpmyadmin/ asking for user and pass.

Now all I have to do is to set a password for localhost and no one will be able to do anything to the database from outside the symfony app (hopefully)